# How to fetch object array from node using Axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I need to store the data from the response in state. once the axios call has been made and returned some data, the useEffect function will be called and cause the task list array to be populated. The result of which can then be iterated over and displayed on the front end.

```
import{ useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

function Todo() {
  const [toDos,setToDos] =useState([])
  function HandleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let request ={

      list : toDos
  }

  let taskList = axios.post('http://localhost:8080/Todo',request)
        .then(resp=>{
            alert(resp.data.message);
        })
        .catch( err=>{
            console.log(err);
        })

        const [tasks,setTasks] = useState([]);
        useEffect(()=>{
          setTasks(taskList);
        },[taskList]);
    
      }
  
  return (
  
      <div >
        <h1>ToDo List</h1>
        <form onSubmit={HandleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" placeholder=" Add item..." name="list" value={toDos} onChange={(e)=>setToDos(e.target.value)}/>
        {tasks.map(()=>{
          return(
            <div>
              <h1>{tasks}</h1>
            </div>
          )
        })}
        <button id="btn" type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>

      </div>


  );
  }



export default Todo;
```

node code

```
const lists =[
    {toDo:"learn react"}
]
app.post('/Todo',function(req, res){

            lists.push({ "toDo":req.body.list})
    console.log(lists)
    res.status(200).send({ message: "Task added!!"})
 }
 )
```

```
 Line 23:16:  'tasks' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

ERROR in [eslint]
src\Todoapp\Todo.js
  Line 36:10:  'tasks' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 39:20:  'tasks' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

this is error anyone can please help

Comment: Did you used useState and useEffect inside the function used it in component level

Answer (score 0):

Define state and in component level and remove `useEffect`. Don't define state and effect in functional level

```
function Todo() { 
   const [tasks,setTasks] = useState([]);
 

   .....
```

Then set the values inside the `then`

```
 axios.post('http://localhost:8080/Todo',request)
    .then(resp=>{
       setTasks(resp.data.message);
    })
    .catch( err=>{
        console.log(err);
    })   

  }
```

Comment: where to declare the taskList  (let taskList = axios.post('http://localhost:8080/Todo',request)  @Sachila Ranawaka, iam a beginner

Comment: don't need to assign a axio to variable